# Sharing Data From One Component To Another

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, data-sharing

**Scope:**

Hi,

I have simple Ionic Angular app. It has 2 Tabs and 1 Page. One Tab2, there's a list of dates that are being displaying by a service that reads a static JSON file. When the user selects a specific date, it should go to the Page (page-one) and display extra details for that specific date.

**What I have so far:**

Currently, just for testing purposes, I am sharing static, hard-coded data from Tab2 to the Page (page-one).

Tab2.html file:

```js
  <ion-list *ngFor="let item of outbreak; let i = index;">
    <ion-item [routerLink] = "['/page-one', 'This is the data from Tab2']">{{ item.date }}</ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Page-one.ts file:

```js
export class PageOnePage implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  data: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data= this.route.snapshot.params.id;
    console.dir(this.route.snapshot);
  }
```

And of course, I updated the app-routing.module.ts file with:

```
  {
    path: 'page-one/:id',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/page-one/page-one.module').then( m => m.PageOnePageModule)
  }
```

**The question/issue:**

I did try

```
ts
<ion-item routerLink="/page-one" fragment="outbreak-{{ i }}">{{ item.date }}</ion-item>
```

in Tab2.html file, which did properly format the URL, but again, after it forwarded to page-one, no data is displaying. So, when the user clicks a date/index from the list, it should route them to page-one and display details for that specific date. I guess I can like read which index/date was clicked on by reading the URL and then displaying it? Not sure, but hopefully someone can help. I'd like to either use routerLink or router.navigate only please.

Thanks!

For reference, the JSON file is an array of objects:

```
[
    {
      "date": "2020-11-01",
      "outbreak_group": "1 Congregate Care",
      "outbreak_subgroup": "1 Long-Term Care Homes",
      "number_ongoing_outbreaks": 73
    },
    ...
    ...
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of options to share data between components. You can read more here:

[Google -> Sharing data between components](https://www.google.com/search?q=sharing%20data%20angular&rlz=1C5CHFA_enAR930AR930&oq=sharing%20data%20angular&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59j69i60l6.2208j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

However you can try the next:

Tab2.html

```
 <ion-list *ngFor="let item of outbreak; let i = index;">
    <ion-item (click)="goToItem(item)">
        {{ item.date }}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Tab2.ts

```
constructor(private navCtrl: NavController)

public goToItem(item){
   this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/path/to/page1',{queryParams:{item}})
}
```

Page1.ts

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
//...
export class YourPageOne {
  public item = null;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        if(params && params.item)
          this.item = params["item"];
    });
}
```

It is not the best, just is one option. The best option depends of each case

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways for sharing the data between the components.

- Best recommended way for Sharing data by using [Singleton Service](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services). Example:[here](https://www.thirdrocktechkno.com/blog/are-the-angular-services-singleton/)
- If component have parent child relationship then you can pass your data through [@Input()](https://angular.io/api/core/Input) and [@Output()](https://angular.io/api/core/Output) parameter. Example [here](https://medium.com/@onejohi/sharing-data-between-components-in-angularjs-c34ff20b7fee)
- If components are same level or siblings then you can also use [Subject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/subject) and [BehaviorSubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject) form [RxJs operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects). Example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-angular-behaviorsubject-to-share-data)

For your scenario `Subject` and `BehaviorSubject` suits best as you want to share data between two tabs. However, you can still check on the basis of your application which method can be use.